# Android Kotlin Broad Receiever in RecyclerAdapter Won't Communicate to Broadcast Receiever in MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

Context: No receiver is declared in the manifest since I am not declaring a new receiver.

I am a bit confused about why the receiver in MainActivity does not receieve the broadcast sent from the recycler adapter.

RecyclerAdapter

```
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener {view ->
            item.completed = holder.checkBox.isChecked
            Log.i("wow", "is checked: ${holder.checkBox.isChecked}")
            val intent = Intent().apply {
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
                setAction(changeCompletedForDeck)
                putExtra(changeCompletedForDeckItemID, item)
            }
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(view.context).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

MainActivity

```
 private lateinit var broadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver

          broadcastReceiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
           override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
               //get deck, if deck != null then update the checkmark response
               if (intent?.action == DeckRecyclerAdapter.changeCompletedForDeck) {
                   val deck = intent?.extras?.getParcelable<Deck>(DeckRecyclerAdapter.changeCompletedForDeckItemID)
                   Log.i("wow", "${deck?.title}")
                   deck?.let { deck ->
                       globalViewModel.update(deck)
                   }
               }
           }
       }
val filter = IntentFilter(DeckRecyclerAdapter.changeCompletedForDeck)
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter)


    //Destroy the BroadcastReceiver
    override fun onDestroy() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Comment: I don't see `registerReceiver` in your `MainActivity` where did you registered it ?

Comment: @ADM Updated, sorry forgot to link it. Is my issue related to not having anything in the Android Manifest file?

Comment: No its not related to manifest . Chekout the answer below See if you understand what i am implying. If you need code sample i will add it too .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `Intent` action . See at the time of register you have not provided any action so receiver will not be identified by the system.
You can define a specific action with `IntentFilter` and use the same action during register and `sendBroadcast`.

To identify different conditions you can do two things.

1. you can set data in `Bundle` and validate the bundle value inside `onReceive()`
2. you can also add multiple  actions to `IntentFilter` and validate the action inside `onReceive()` [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128103/broadcastreceiver-with-multiple-filters-or-multiple-broadcastreceivers).

So with the first way have a constant action in `MainActivity`:-

```
companion object{
    const val BROADCAST_ACTION="LIST_CHECK_ACTION"
}


LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION)).
```

Then for sending broadcast use the code below `addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)` is not required:-

```
val intent = Intent().apply {
        action = MainAcvity.BROADCAST_ACTION
        putExtra("item", item)
    }
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(view.context).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

**PS-**  However i don't think you should be using a `Broadcastreceiver` just to provide a callback from `Adapter` its purpose is more than that. You should be using a callback listener for it . Since `RecyclerView.Adapter` will binds to a UI component a callback interface will be fine . I think a `broadcastReceiver` is overkill in this usecase .

Comment: Can you please clarify, I am getting the gist of what you are saying. But all I need is the intent from recycler view as all I require is passing a single parcelable object. I am a bit confused with the IntentFilter, as they are supposedly matching the action. But an intent also has an action etc. Also I only require one action anyway. Thus, I have initialised in the constructor

Comment: Just one last thing as I now understand what prevented the code from working. (I'll mark this response as the answer).
Okay, so following what you had in the code snippet. The thing that prevented the code from executing was addCategory. How does that play a part and prevent the broadcaster from working? is it used for multiple possibilities?

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_DEFAULT) should answer your question.